# Export and Import between SVN repositories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using Tortoise 1.9.5.
We have an internal SVN with client sources for developing.
Periodically we need to move changes between our and client trunk so thought about this solution:
1) Tortoise Export from our repo to a new clean folder.
2) Tortoise Import from unversioned folder to client repo.

But when I choose Import I've an error:

Import C:\RDS_1 to http://xxx.yyy.zzz.kkk/repo/sw/ERMES/trunk/RDS_1
The HTTP method 'MKCOL' is not allowed on
 '/repo/!svn/txr/126816-2ywx/sw/ERMES/trunk/RDS_1/Common'

So this method is not applicable, how can I do for update client repo?

Thanks

Alessio

Comment: I want to note that using IP address in the URL is a bad practice. Use FQDN / hostname to contact the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- checkout your destination working copy (already done)
- copy the exported files into to target folder (done as well)
- right-click TortoiseSVN->Add on new folder (or svn command "svn add ")
- right-click TortoieSVN->Commit

Done